# Using mocked objects (Moq) with methods that use reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, wcf, moq

So I have a use case where a generic method in a base controller class takes in a collection of services and returns the correct one (V1, V2, etc) based off the URI or a header that has the Version number.  Here it is below.

```
protected T GetService<T>(List<T> services)
        {
            return URI.Contains("v1") ? services.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType().ToString().Contains("1")) :
                                        services.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType().ToString().Contains(GetVersionFromHeader(WebContext)));
        }
```

This method works wonderfully in practice because our services all have their version number appended to them as such [ServiceName]V1, [ServiceNameV2], etc.

The issue now is that this breaks a lot of existing unit tests because this method often returns back null when the collection of `services` is a collection of mocked interfaces that each return a type of `Castle.Proxies.ObjectProxy`.  I really can't push these changes if I have to remove a quarter of our unit tests.  I probably could hard-code a condition that checks whether this is a test or not, but I'd prefer not to commit an hacky fix like that.

If anybody has experience or ideas with retrieving the actual mocked type or workarounds from problems like this that stem from using reflection and then testing those methods with Mocked objects would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!